# Why my authors profile pictures are not visible?

Tags: python, django

So, like in title I have a problem with authors profile pictures which doesn't show as you can see on the photo.

I learn Django from Corey Schafer's tutorials and in his video everything was fine, I have no idea why it occurs to me.

[image: My problem]

[image: Author profile]

**views.py**

```
posts = [
    {
        'author': 'Eldzej02',
        'title': 'Birthday',
        'content': 'A birthday is the anniversary of the birth of a person, or figuratively of an institution. Birthdays of people are celebrated in numerous cultures, often with birthday gifts, birthday cards, a birthday party, or a rite of passage.',
        'date': '10 May 2021',
    },
    {
        'author': 'AFX',
        'title': 'Previous day',
        'content': 'I didn\'t feel well the previous day, i must say.',
        'date': '11 May 2021',
    },
    {
        'author': 'AFX',
        'title': 'Today\'s day',
        'content': 'Today was sunny at the morning but later, during the noon it started raining',
        'date': '12 May 2021',
    }
]

def index(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context['parent_template'] = 'home.html'
        context['posts'] = posts
    else:
        context['parent_template'] = 'index_not_auth.html'
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**home.html** (problem)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
          <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
            <div class="media-body">
              <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date }}</small>
              </div>
              <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
              <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In my opinion problem occurs by path post.author.profile.image.url ,but i don't why. What do you think?

**profile.html** (correct)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Profile{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="content-section">
            <div class="media">
              <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
              <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
                <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Data</legend>
                  {{ u_form|crispy }}
                  {{ p_form|crispy }}
              </fieldset>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
              </div>
          </form>
          </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        context['parent_template'] = 'home.html'
        context['posts'] = posts
    else:
        context['parent_template'] = 'index_not_auth.html'
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'u_form':u_form, 
        'p_form':p_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

Comment: You reference `post.author.profile.image.url` - but there is no `profile` key in your list; just a single `author` key. I'm guessing you'd want something like `{'author': {'profile': {'image': {'url': 'https://....'}, 'name': 'Profilename'} } }` in your dictionary.

Comment: Beacouse profile is already in models.py `class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'`

Comment: can you share the view that renders profile.html

Comment: The `author` entries in the `posts` dictionaries are just strings. They happen to be usernames, but django doesn't know that. If you want to access the profile, `author` needs to be a User instance... not a string.

Comment: @evergreen can u explain me why in this repository it works, but to me it doesn't? 
 Corey's repository - https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Django_Blog/09-Update-User-Profile/django_project This repository is the same to my in my opinion. MY - https://github.com/Inexpli/Django-WebApp

Comment: Corey's code has a `Post` model with an `author` field, which is a ForeignKey to`User`, so django knows that the `author` field is an instance of `User`.

Comment: When you reference an unknown attribute in a template, like `post.author.profile` in your code, the template just silently fails and substitutes an empty string. If you referenced `post.author.profile` in a view, for example, it would give you an error message.

Comment: You never use the model - you only assign a static list of entries to the template from your view. If you want to use your model, you'll have to fetch the data from the model instead of using the static data as @evergreen described. In the linked repo you can see that he calls `Post.objects.all()` when assigning data to the context, instead of using a static list as you have in your question (and in your repo).

Comment: Ah, sorry. Now i realised that this part with database to Posts he made in videos earlier which i just skipped because I was some ahead. Thank all you very much for help.